# Selecting an id from a variable

Tags: javascript, selector

I'm using websockets with ruby, but my problem is with javascript. I'm trying to access the img location using the pic variable. I remember using a "parse" command but I cant remember where saw it online.

```
<body>
  <div id ="a0">
    <img class = "image" src="">
    <br>
    <p class = "info"></p>
  </div>

  <div id ="a1">
    <img class = "image" src="">
    <br>
    <p class = "info"></p>
  </div>
</body> 



:javascript 
  var msg = {"selector" : "a0", "image" : "image0.jpg", "info" : "picture"};
  var pic = document.getElementById(msg["selector"]);
```

This is the problem

```
  pic.select(".image").src = msg["image"];
  pic.select(".info").innerHTML = msg["info"];
```

Comment: I should mention that id's are required to be unique...you have more than 1 id with the name "image" and "info"

Comment: Using Nokogiri in ruby I can access both of these quite fine. ("div#a0 img") I don't see why this is bad etiquette.

Comment: Because like phantom said ID's are meant to be unique.

Comment: @user2446058 It's not a matter of etiquette, it's a matter of fact.  This is required by W3C as seen here in section 7.5.2: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Comment: Because `id` is unique according to the HTML specs, and depending on *undefined behaviour* is **bad**

Comment: Vanilla js `pic.src = msg["image"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <div id ="a0">
    <img class = "image" src="">
    <br>
    <p class = "info"></p>
  </div>
  <div id ="a1">
    <img class = "image" src="">
    <br>
    <p class = "info"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Try this

```
pic.querySelector(".image").src = msg["image"];
pic.querySelector(".info").innerHTML = msg["info"];
```

Comment: I'm getting a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" error in console. I'm using pure js. I'm not sure the select method is the right one to use.

Comment: Ok - I have modified the answer so it reflects your query selector method - did the html work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its the method "querySelector"

```
element = document.querySelector(selectors);

pic.querySelector(".image").src = msg["image"];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector